# Sum of Digits till a number which is given as input

Tags: algorithm

If a number is given as an input find sum of all the digits of number till that number

For example 11 is input then answer is 1+2....+9+(1+0)+(1+1)
The Brute-force method would be to calculate sum of digits of all the numbers that are less than a number.I have implemented that method iam wondering if there is any other way to do it without actually calculating sum of digits of every number

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that faster (in O(log n) operations). Let `S(n)` be the sum of the digits of all numbers `0 <= k < n`. Then

```
S(10*n) = 10*S(n) + 45*n
```

because among the numbers less than `10*n`, each `k < n` appears as the initial part of a number 10 times, with last digits `0, 1, ..., 9`. So that contributes 45 for the sum of the last digits, and 10 times the sum of the digits of `k`.

Reversing that, we find

```
S(n) = 10*S(n/10) + 45*(n/10) + (n%10)*DS(n/10) + (n%10)*((n%10)-1)/2
```

where `DS(k)` is the plain digit sum of `k`. The first two terms come from the above, the remaining two come from the sum of the digits of `n - n%10, ..., n - n%10 + (n%10 + 1)`.

Start is `S(n) = 0` for `n <= 1`.

To include the upper bound, call it as `S(n+1)`.

Comment: please explain how did u arrive with these two terms (n%10)*DS(n/10) + (n%10)*((n%10)-1)/2

Comment: Say `n = 10*k + r`. Then we need the digit sums of `10*k`, `10*k + 1`, ..., `10*k + (r-1)`. Those are `r = n%10` numbers, all starting with `k`. That part gives the `(n%10)*DS(n/10) = r*DS(k)`. The last is the sum of the final digits, `0, ..., r-1`, which is `r*(r-1)/2`.

Answer (score -1):

Let us take few examples.

> sum(9) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ........... + 9
>          = 9*10/2 
>          = 45
>
> sum(99)  = 45 + (10 + 45) + (20 + 45) + ..... (90 + 45)
>            = 45*10 + (10 + 20 + 30 ... 90)
>            = 45*10 + 10(1 + 2 + ... 9)
>            = 45*10 + 45*10
>            = sum(9)*10 + 45*10
>
> sum(999) = sum(99)*10 + 45*100

In general, we can compute sum(10d – 1) using below formula

> sum(10d - 1) = sum(10d-1 - 1) * 10 + 45*(10d-1)

In below implementation, the above formula is implemented using dynamic programming as there are overlapping subproblems.
The above formula is one core step of the idea. Below is complete algorithm

> Algorithm: sum(n)
>
> 1) Find number of digits minus one in n. Let this value be 'd'.
>   For 328, d is 2.
>
> 2) Compute some of digits in numbers from 1 to 10d - 1.      Let this
>   sum be w. For 328, we compute sum of digits from 1 to     99 using
>   above formula.
>
> 3) Find Most significant digit (msd) in n. For 328, msd is 3.
>
> 4) Overall sum is sum of following terms
>
> ```
> a) Sum of digits in 1 to "msd * 10d - 1".  For 328, sum of 
>    digits in numbers from 1 to 299.
>     For 328, we compute 3*sum(99) + (1 + 2)*100.  Note that sum of
>     sum(299) is sum(99) + sum of digits from 100 to 199 + sum of digits
>     from 200 to 299.  
>     Sum of 100 to 199 is sum(99) + 1*100 and sum of 299 is sum(99) + 2*100.
>     In general, this sum can be computed as w*msd + (msd*(msd-1)/2)*10d
>
> b) Sum of digits in msd * 10d to n.  For 328, sum of digits in 
>    300 to 328.
>     For 328, this sum is computed as 3*29 + recursive call "sum(28)"
>     In general, this sum can be computed as  msd * (n % (msd*10d) + 1) 
>     + sum(n % (10d))
> ```

Below is C++ implementation of above aglorithm.

```
// C++ program to compute sum of digits in numbers from 1 to n
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Function to computer sum of digits in numbers from 1 to n
// Comments use example of 328 to explain the code
int sumOfDigitsFrom1ToN(int n)
{
    // base case: if n<10 return sum of
    // first n natural numbers
    if (n<10)
      return n*(n+1)/2;

    // d = number of digits minus one in n. For 328, d is 2
    int d = log10(n);

    // computing sum of digits from 1 to 10^d-1,
    // d=1 a[0]=0;
    // d=2 a[1]=sum of digit from 1 to 9 = 45
    // d=3 a[2]=sum of digit from 1 to 99 = a[1]*10 + 45*10^1 = 900
    // d=4 a[3]=sum of digit from 1 to 999 = a[2]*10 + 45*10^2 = 13500
    int *a = new int[d+1];
    a[0] = 0, a[1] = 45;
    for (int i=2; i<=d; i++)
        a[i] = a[i-1]*10 + 45*ceil(pow(10,i-1));

    // computing 10^d
    int p = ceil(pow(10, d));

    // Most significant digit (msd) of n,
    // For 328, msd is 3 which can be obtained using 328/100
    int msd = n/p;

    // EXPLANATION FOR FIRST and SECOND TERMS IN BELOW LINE OF CODE
    // First two terms compute sum of digits from 1 to 299
    // (sum of digits in range 1-99 stored in a[d]) +
    // (sum of digits in range 100-199, can be calculated as 1*100 + a[d]
    // (sum of digits in range 200-299, can be calculated as 2*100 + a[d]
    //  The above sum can be written as 3*a[d] + (1+2)*100

    // EXPLANATION FOR THIRD AND FOURTH TERMS IN BELOW LINE OF CODE
    // The last two terms compute sum of digits in number from 300 to 328
    // The third term adds 3*29 to sum as digit 3 occurs in all numbers 
    //                from 300 to 328
    // The fourth term recursively calls for 28
    return msd*a[d] + (msd*(msd-1)/2)*p +  
           msd*(1+n%p) + sumOfDigitsFrom1ToN(n%p);
}

// Driver Program
int main()
{
    int n = 328;
    cout << "Sum of digits in numbers from 1 to " << n << " is "
         << sumOfDigitsFrom1ToN(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Sum of digits in numbers from 1 to 328 is 3241
```

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-sum-of-digits-in-numbers-from-1-to-n/

Comment: you should have given the link instead of copying the content.