# Find the sum of the digits of all the numbers from 1 to N

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

Problem:
**Find the sum of the digits of all the numbers from 1 to N (both ends included)**

**Time Complexity should be O(logN)**

For N = 10 the sum is 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0) = 46

For N = 11 the sum is 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0)+(1+1) = 48

For N = 12 the sum is 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0)+(1+1) +(1+2)= 51

This recursive [solution](https://yiyang.li/2015/06/09/code-wars-an-online-self-training-platform/) works like a charm, but I'd like to understand the rationale for reaching such a solution. I believe it's based on finite induction, but can someone show exactly how to solve this problem?

I've pasted (with minor modifications) the aforementioned solution:

```
static long Solution(long n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    if (n < 10)
        return (n * (n + 1)) / 2; // sum of arithmetic progression
    long x = long.Parse(n.ToString().Substring(0, 1)); // first digit
    long y = long.Parse(n.ToString().Substring(1)); // remaining digits
    int power = (int)Math.Pow(10, n.ToString().Length - 1);

    // how to reach this recursive solution?
    return (power * Solution(x - 1))
    + (x * (y + 1)) 
    + (x * Solution(power - 1)) 
    + Solution(y);
}
```

Unit test (which is NOT O(logN)):

```
    long count = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<=N; i++)
    {
        foreach (var c in i.ToString().ToCharArray())
            count += int.Parse(c.ToString());
    }
```

Or:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, N).SelectMany(
    n => n.ToString().ToCharArray().Select(
        c => int.Parse(c.ToString())
    )
).Sum();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is considered a duplicate. The problem description is the same, but my question actually is "Why this formula works". And the formula is very different from the one answered in the other question. The other thread didn't had an algebraic explanation of the solution, as I have answered here. If this is a duplicate, please accept my apologies.

Comment: There is nothing to apologies about. You have made some work around the question and even posted and answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a `O(n^log10(2))`-time solution (`log10(2)` is approximately `0.3`). Not sure if that matters. We have `n = xy`, where I use concatenation to denote concatenation, not multiplication. Here are the four key lines with commentary underneath.

```
return (power * Solution(x - 1))
```

This counts the contribution of the `x` place for the numbers from `1` inclusive to `x*power` exclusive. This recursive call doesn't contribute to the complexity because it returns in constant time.

```
+ (x * (y + 1))
```

This counts the contribution of the `x` place for the numbers from `x*power` inclusive to `n` inclusive.

```
+ (x * Solution(power - 1))
```

This counts the contribution of the lower-order places for the numbers from `1` inclusive to `x*power` exclusive. This call is on a number one digit shorter than `n`.

```
+ Solution(y);
```

This counts the contribution of the lower-order places for the numbers from `x*power` inclusive to `n` inclusive. This call is on a number one digit shorter than `n`.

We get the time bound from applying Case 1 of the Master Theorem. To get the running time down to `O(log n)`, we can compute `Solution(power - 1)` analytically. I don't remember offhand what the closed form is.

Comment: [`Solution(power - 1)` is equal to `45 * n * (int)Math.Pow(10,n-1)`, where `n` is log₁₀(power)](http://oeis.org/A034967)

Answer (score 0):

After thinking for a while (and finding [similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371524/sum-of-digits-till-a-number-which-is-given-as-input)), I guess I could achieve the rationale that gave me another solution.

**Definitions**
Let S(n) be the sum of the digits of all numbers 0 <= k < n.
Let D(k) be the plain digits sum of k only.
(I'll omit parentheses for   >clarity, so consider Dx = D(x)

If n>=10, let's **decompose n by spliting the last digit and the tens (n = 10*k + r)** (k, r being integers)

We need to sum S(n) = S(10*k + r) = S(10*k) + D(10*k+1) + ... + D(10*k+r)

The first part, S(10*k), follows a pattern:
S(10*1)=D1+D2+D3+...+D9     =(1+2+3+...+9) *1                                             + D10
S(10*2)=D1+D2+D3+...+D19    =(1+2+3+...+9) *2   +1*9               +D10                    + D20
S(10*3)=D1+D2+D3+...+D29    =(1+2+3+...+9) *3   +1*9+2*9           +D10+...+D20            + D30

So **S(10*k)** = (1+2+3+...+9)*k + 9*S(k-1) + S(k-1) + D(10*k) = **45*k + 10*S(k-1) + D(10*k)**

Regarding the last part, we know that D(10*k+x) = D(10*k)+D(x) = D(k)+x, so this last part can be simplified:

D(10*k+1) + ... + D(10*k+r) = D(k)+1 + D(k)+2 + ... D(k)+r = r*D(k) + (1+2+...+r) = **r***D(k) + r*(1+r)/2

So, adding both parts of the equation (and grouping D(k)) we have:
**S(n) = 45*k + 10*S(k-1) + (1+r)D(k) + r*(1+r)/2**

And replacing k and r we have:
**S(n) = 45*k + 10*S((n/10)-1) + (1+n%10)*D(n/10) + n%10*(1+n%10)/2**

**Pseudocode**:

```
S(n):
  if n=0, sum=0
  if n<10, n*(1+n)/2
  r=n%10 # let's decompose n = 10*k + r (being k, r integers). 
  k=n/10
  return 45*k + 10*S((n/10)-1) + (1+n%10)*D(n/10) + n%10*(1+n%10)/2
D(n):
  just sum digits
```

**First algorithm (the one from the original question) in C#**

```
static BigInteger Solution(BigInteger n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    if (n < 10)
        return (n * (n + 1)) / 2; // sum of arithmetic progression
    long x = long.Parse(n.ToString().Substring(0, 1)); // first digit
    long y = long.Parse(n.ToString().Substring(1)); // remaining digits
    BigInteger power = BigInteger.Pow(10, n.ToString().Length - 1);
    var log = Math.Round(BigInteger.Log10(power)); // BigInteger.Log10 can give rounding errors like 2.99999

    return (power * Solution(x - 1)) //This counts the contribution of the x place for the numbers from 1 inclusive to x*power exclusive. This recursive call doesn't contribute to the complexity because it returns in constant time.
    + (x * (y + 1)) //This counts the contribution of the x place for the numbers from x*power inclusive to n inclusive.
    //+ (x * Solution(power - 1)) // This counts the contribution of the lower-order places for the numbers from 1 inclusive to x*power exclusive. This call is on a number one digit shorter than n.
    + (x * 45*new BigInteger(log)* BigInteger.Pow(10,(int)log-1)) // 
    + Solution(y);
}
```

**Second algorithm (deduced from formula above) in C#**

```
static BigInteger Solution2(BigInteger n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    if (n < 10)
        return (n * (n + 1)) / 2; // sum of arithmetic progression
    BigInteger r = BigInteger.ModPow(n, 1, 10); // decompose n = 10*k + r
    BigInteger k = BigInteger.Divide(n, 10);
    return 45 * k
         + 10*Solution2(k-1)                      // 10*S((n/10)-1)
         + (1+r) * (k.ToString().ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).Sum()) //  (1+n%10)*D(n/10)
         + (r * (r + 1)) / 2;                     //n%10*(1+n%10)/2
}
```

**EDIT**: According to my tests, it's running faster than both the original version (which was using recursion twice), and the version modified to calculate **Solution(power - 1)** in a single step.

PS: I'm not sure, but I guess that if I had splitted the **first** digit of the number instead of the **last**, maybe I could achieve a solution like the original algorithm.